# Python: How to pass function with two parameters as an argument

Tags: python, function, arguments

i have a problem:

I need to implement a function in python which prints a skalar multiple of an argument - the argument is a function itself which has the signature:

```
def innerF(a,b):
    return x
```

The skalar multiplier is a constant within the function - e.g.

`return 55 * x`

Now comes the part i dont seem to get:
The call Sytanx is required to be:

`print( outerF(innerF)(a,b))`

So in summary

```
def innerF(a,b):
    return a + b

def outerF( #What goes here? ):
    return 55* #How two call the innerF?

print(outerF(innerF)(a,b))
```

What i know so far:

- I can pass the innerF an the a,b as seperate arguments to outerF like

  def outerF(innerF,a,b):
  return 53* innerF(a,b)

What i dont get:

The signature of the outerF call with `innerF(outerF)(a,b)` is completly unknow to me. Also i could not find refernce.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you need is nested functions.

```py
outerF(innerF)(a, b)
```

means `outerF(innerF)` returns a new function that then takes `a` and `b` as arguments.

To achieve this you need a function that returns a function.

```py
def inner(a, b):
    return a + b

def outer(func):
    def wrapper(a, b):
        return 55 * func(a, b)
    return wrapper

outer(inner)(2, 3) # 275
```

You could also apply the outer function as a decorator.

```py
@outer
def inner(a, b):
    return a + b
    
inner(2, 3) # 275
```

Comment: Thank you very much - works as required!

Answer (score 6):

`outerF` needs to return a function that is getting called with `(a, b)`

```
def innerF(a, b):
    return a + b


def outerF(func):
    # define a function to return
    def f(*args, **kwargs):
        # this just calls the given func & scales it
        return 55 * func(*args, **kwargs)

    return f


print(outerF(innerF)(1, 2))
```

Result:

```
165  # 55 * (1+2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much - works as required!